# An unexpected horizontal line appears at the page bottom when printing a multi-page HTML table with thead - how to remove it?

Tags: html, css

See pic:
[image]

This only happens when:

1. There is a `thead`;
2. There is an CSS preventing table items to be broken down between pages and set the border style, namely:

   ```css
   table {
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   ```

What's more, this line seems to be very very thin.

Full page source here: (Zoom in to see the horizontal line.)

```js
$(function() {
  function set_row(row) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      $('<td>').html(i).appendTo(row)
    return row
  }

  function new_row() {
    return set_row($('<tr>'))
  }

  set_row($('tr')) // initialize thead
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    $('table').append(new_row())

  window.print()
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem when testing the snippet from my end with Chrome and Edge

Comment: @Kyojimaru Strange, I am using the latest Edge (Chromium kernel). I have saved the PDF here: [sample](https://github.com/yanhuihang/Uploads/raw/main/css%20-%20An%20unexpected%20horizontal%20line%20appears%20at%20the%20page%20bottom%20when%20printing%20a%20multi-page%20HTML%20table%20with%20thead%20-%20how%20to%20remove%20it_%20-%20Stack%20Overflow.pdf), where the mysterious horizontal line can be observed.

Comment: tried your sample and opened it in Chrome at 100% zoom level it appeared, at 175% it almost diminish, then appeared again till 400% zoom level and gone at 500% zoom level, same results on Edge, perhaps it's just rendering problem. Have you tested it and see if it's really there when it's printed?

Comment: @Kyojimaru Same results here, if keep zooming the line will appear again. Just tried printing and it was recorded on paper.

Answer (score 0):

add to `<thead>` style `border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;`